# How to execute python script in ionic framework similarly it execute in a php file

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to execute a python script in ionic as we execute python script in php
Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, python scripts are not executed in Ionic. By writing python code we can though, access services which are written in Python by writing the API call from 'providers' in ionic.

Comment: is it possible with django?

Comment: i really want this so that my project can run on mobile phone. can u suggest me something

Comment: In django, do you want to expose data to web api or anything else?  Maybe this video can be of help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVDjoTt3r8A